# Dynamic footer row prints outside the content area

Tags: livecycle-designer, xfa, table-footer

I'm using LiveCycle Designer ES 8.2.1. I also have a web application injecting data into the report I created with LiveCycle. The basic structure is the following:

1 Master page with 1 page and a content area containing a table filled with a list of object. My table has 1 header row, 2 body rows and a footer row that is added dynamically with page break condition.

The logic behind that is written in FormCalc. Our objects are sent as a list which fills either one or the other body row based on a type. Each object has an "authority" property with a certain value that are used to mark the pages. The list of object is sorted by authority. So, when the current iterating object has a different authority than the previous one, we insert a page brake and the footer row. Everything is wraped in a subform that is "In Content Area" (Object/Pagination/Place).

The problem is that the footer row is not considered as part of the content area. If the last line of a section fits tight in the content area, the footer row overflows outside the content area and even the whole page in some cases.

Here are more details:
We tried any combination of subform wraping and ticking of the "Allow page break with content" check box.
We tried changing the type of the footer row for a body row in case footers were different than body rows.
We tried every combination of "Keep with" and "place".
We tried to change the footer row to a body row and have it displayed on every page and that work, but our client refused the solution...
Starting with the above (pt 4) template and changing back the body to footer row brought us to the begining
To the best of our knowledge, we tried everyting possible...

What I'm looking for is either a confirmed bug for version 8.2.1 about this or a solution other than redesigning the whole report.

Comment: Can you share your form? It would facilitate finding problem and fixing it.

Comment: I know this won't help, but I cannot. I'm not authorized to do so. I was just wondering if someone could have  brought something we didn't think of. I also tried with the latest version of designer and the same problem occurs.